# Cron jobs not sending image on time

Tags: php, cron

I have set the cron jobs to 0 23 * * * 
it means it should be send email at 11PM....But its not sending emails..
But when i change the time to * * * * *
Means when i set time after every minute than cron job is working fine..

[image]

I want that everyday at 11PM cron jobs should send email ..........

Please help me what is the issue?

Comment: there are many possibilities. most common one is that your server time is not what you think it is . do echo "The time is " . date("h:i:sa"); to see if it is correct.

Comment: so it will still send every 24 hours.. just look at an email header and see when the server sent it and adjust cron times according.. Incidentally you might want to set one to run a minute or two after the first

Comment: thanks both of u.. it was time issue...

Comment: @Dimi may i know one thing? what is diffrence between this command (wget -O /dev/null -o /dev/null http://www.jobsrope.com/jobsite/weekly_job_hunting_jobseeker) and this command (wget  http://www.jobsrope.com/jobsite/weekly_job_hunting_jobseeker)

Comment: wget downloads a file. doing wget -O /dev/null means 'download this file and throw it away'.  wget url makes it actually save a file in your directory. Alternatively you can use 'curl $url'.

Comment: which one is more good in both of the above?